# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class error while executing pyspark code with deequ libraries

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am getting " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class" error for the below code in databricks with deequ 1.0.5 libraries. Any help to fix this issue or any work around will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ramabadran

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import sagemaker_pyspark
import pydeequ
from pydeequ.analyzers import *
from pydeequ.verification import *
from pydeequ.suggestions import *


classpath = ":".join(sagemaker_pyspark.classpath_jars())


spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Sales_Transaction_Full_load") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath) \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord) \
    .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord) \
    .getOrCreate()

storage_account_name = "xxxxxxx"
storage_account_access_key = "xxxxx"

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",storage_account_access_key)
blob_file_type = "csv"



blob_folder_order = "xxxxxxx"

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
print(timestr)
try :
  

  df = spark.read.format(blob_file_type).option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load(blob_folder_order)
  suggestionResult = ConstraintSuggestionRunner(spark) \
             .onData(df) \
             .addConstraintRule(DEFAULT()) \
             .run()
  print(json.dumps(suggestionResult, indent=2))
   
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you’re running this version that isn’t compatible with databricks runtime version. Deequ 1.0.5 had a problem with Spark 3, so it’s better to use version 1.2.2 that is latest

Answer (score 0):

deequ 1.0.5 libraries runs with Scala 2.11, therefore you need to use Databricks Runtime Version **6.4 or less**.
By the way, when using Databricks 6.4, '%pip install pydeequ' is not available yet. You will need to '%sh pip install pydeequ'